# Rails - strip xml import from whitespace and line break

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, whitespace, nokogiri, line-breaks

I am stuck with something quite simple but really annoying:
I have an xml file with one node, where the content includes line breaks and whitspaces.
Sadly I can't change the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ProductFeed>
```

ACME Ltd.
    
    Fooproduct
    
    Foo Root :: Bar Category

I get to the node and can read from it without trouble:

```
url = "http://feeds.somefeed/feed.xml.gz"
@source = open((url), :http_basic_authentication=>["USER", "PW"])
@gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(@source)
@result = @gz.read
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(@result)
@doc.xpath("/ProductFeed/Vendors/Vendor").each do |manuf|
vendor = manuf.css("Name").first.text
manuf.xpath("//child::Product").each do |product|   

  product_name = product.css("Name").text
  foocat = product.css("Category").text

  puts "#{vendor} ---- #{product_name} ---- #{foocat} "
 end
end
```

This results in:

```
ACME Ltd. ---- Fooproduct ----
                                      Foo Root :: Bar Category
```

Obviously there are line breaks and tab stops or spaces in the string returned by product.css("Category").text.

**Does anyone know how to strip the result from linebreaks and taps or spaces right here?**

Alternatively I could do that in the next step, where I do a find on 'foocat' like

```
barcat = Category.find_by_foocat(foocat)
```

Thanks for helping!

Val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [use XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499356/xslt-how-to-ignore-unnecessary-white-space) to remove all the unnecessary characters.

Comment: Hi Santiiii,
thanks for the idea! I hadn't used any xslt before and it looks great and worked for testing. For completeness: I actually ended up calling '.text).strip' on the desired node.
    cat = (product.css("Category").text).strip
The reason is that my specific setup with nokogiri made it easier that way.