# XSL Strip Padding

Tags: xml, string, xslt, exslt

Is there a simple way to strip padding, IE leading and/or trailing white space. EXSLT padding function seems to only create padding or trim strings to a certain length.

Comment: What is "strip-padding"? please, edit your question and give a concrete example of what you want!

Comment: About white space handling there is more than one scenario... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184431/converting-xml-to-plain-text-using-xslt-how-should-i-ignore-handle-whitespace/185048#185048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would normalize-space() do the job for you? This will also reduce spaces inside the string, e.g.

```
"  this         string    "
```

would become:

```
"this string"
```

If you really need a "trim" function, you can probably [steal one from someone else who's already implemented it](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4032) with normalizse-space()...

Comment: Or one could use the replace function (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace). It should work more or less (i.e. it's untested) like this: `replace(string, '^\s*(.*?)\s*$', '')`.

Answer (score 1):

Try normalize-space

```
<xsl:value-of select='normalize-space(string)'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what is wanted -- what is "strip padding"?

If you meant the trim() function, then

**The [FXSL library](http://fxsl.sf.net) provides a convenient `trim` template function**.

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:import href="trim.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    '<xsl:call-template name="trim">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="string(/*)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>'
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<someText>

   This is    some text   

</someText>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
'This is    some text'
```