# XSLT If node exist print his selected Ancestors and himself

Tags: xslt

I want print C declaration code by XSLT.
Output,if exist node PARAMPOS print his ROOTNAME his FUNCTIONNAME and his PARAMNAME:

MODIFICATION: HOW TRANSFORM CHARACTER "-" TO "_" (OUTPUT MUST BE C LANGUAGE VALID, ONLY ALPHANUMERIC OR UNDERSCORE CHARACTER IS POSSIBLE) in Name-1 (in xml) to Name_1 in output C code text?

```cpp
enum ParamName
{//ROOTNAME_FUNCTIONNAME_PARAMNAME
Bike_Name_1_PopA,
Bike_Name_1_PopB,
Bike_Name_2_PopX,
//last item 
SIGNforLAST
}
```

Output,if exist node PARAMPOS print his FUNCTIONID and the himself PARAMPOS:

```cpp
struct Parameter Parameters[SIGNforLAST - 1]
{//{FUNCTIONID,PARAMPOS},
{1, 51},
{1, 52},
{2, 72}
}
```

from XML

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ROOT>  
    <ROOTNAME>Bike</ROOTNAME>
      <Function> 
        <FunctionID>1</FunctionID>
        <FunctionName>Name-1</FunctionName>
        <FunctionClass>
          <PUParam>
            <ParamName>PopA</ParamName>
            <PUParamOPType>
                <ParamPos>51</ParamPos>
            </PUParamOPType>
          </PUParam>
          <PUParam>
            <ParamName>PopB</ParamName>
            <PUParamOPType>
                <ParamPos>52</ParamPos>
            </PUParamOPType>
          </PUParam>
          <PUParam>
            <ParamName>PopC-without</ParamName>
            <PUParamOPType>
                empty
            </PUParamOPType>
          </PUParam>      
        </FunctionClass>
      </Function>
      <Function> 
        <FunctionID>2</FunctionID>
        <FunctionName>Name-2</FunctionName>
        <FunctionClass>
          <PUParam>
            <ParamName>PopX</ParamName>
            <PUParamOPType>
                <ParamPos>72</ParamPos>
            </PUParamOPType>
          </PUParam>
        </FunctionClass>
      </Function>
    </ROOT>
```

Please help me with xsl. For text output I inspired at [converting-xml-to-plain-text-how-should-i-ignore-handle-whitespace-in-the-xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184431/converting-xml-to-plain-text-how-should-i-ignore-handle-whitespace-in-the-xslt). But my XSL is first attempt.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:transform [
  <!ENTITY s "<xsl:text xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'> </xsl:text>" >
  <!ENTITY s2 "<xsl:text xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>  </xsl:text>" >
  <!ENTITY s4 "<xsl:text xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>    </xsl:text>" >
  <!ENTITY s6 "<xsl:text xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>      </xsl:text>" >
  <!ENTITY e "<xsl:text xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'></xsl:text>" >
  <!ENTITY n "<xsl:text xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
</xsl:text>" >
]>

<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="text"/>



<xsl:template match="ROOTNAME">
<xsl:for-each select="Function">
      <xsl:value-of select="FunctionID"/>&s2;<xsl:value-of select="FunctionName"/>&s2;
            <xsl:value-of select="FunctionClass/PUParam/ParamName"/>&n;
</xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Please post the XSLT you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your given sample XML and output. I have written below XSLT

```
<xsl:transform version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="ROOTNAME">
    <xsl:value-of select="/ROOT/ROOTNAME"/>
</xsl:variable>
enum ParamName
{
<xsl:variable name="temp1">
<xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/Function">
    <xsl:variable name="funcName" select="FunctionName"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="./FunctionClass/PUParam[./PUParamOPType/ParamPos]">
        <temp><xsl:value-of select="concat($ROOTNAME,'_',$funcName,'_',./ParamName)"/>   </temp>            
    </xsl:for-each>        
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="$temp1/temp">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,<xsl:text>&#10;     </xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
SIGNforLAST
}

struct Parameter Parameters[SIGNforLAST - 1]
{
<xsl:variable name="temp2">
<xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/Function">
    <xsl:variable name="funcId" select="FunctionID"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="./FunctionClass/PUParam[./PUParamOPType/ParamPos]">  
        <temp>
            <xsl:value-of  select="concat('{',$funcId,',',./PUParamOPType/ParamPos,'}')"/>    
        </temp>                        
    </xsl:for-each>        
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="$temp2/temp">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,<xsl:text>&#10;     </xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
}
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Out put for givene XML will be as below

```
enum ParamName
{
Bike_Name1_PopA,
Bike_Name1_PopB,
Bike_Name2_PopX
SIGNforLAST
}

struct Parameter Parameters[SIGNforLAST - 1]
{
{1,51},
{1,52},
{2,72}
}

Please update the output as per your requirement. Thanks :)
```

Comment: Your XSL code return me in Notepad++ XMLToolsPlugin ver2.3.2 only text
enum ParamName
{
(no jump into <xsl:variable name="temp1">). In Firefox there was error message: Error during XSLT transformation: An XPath expression should return a set of nodes. What kind of tool can I use? What tool for debug XSL?Thanks

Comment: But in XMLSpy2013 function it well. Thanks!     WHY THE XMLToolPlugin in Notapad++ DON'T EXECUTED THIS?

Comment: XMSpy supports 1.1 version. XMLToolsPlugin ver2.3.2 maynot support version 1.1. I am assigning to node to variable which is not support by XSLT 1.0. Thats why I used 1.1. I have captured complete node to variable to add ',' and new line other than last node.